# How is an S/MIME signed / encrypted email structured?

Tags: smime, mime-message

I'm having trouble interpreting an S/MIME signed / encrypted message. This is the structure I get when I parse a .msg file into JavaMail MimeMessage (and I'm not sure that it matters that it is Java or Outlook):

```
MimeMessage
   - FROM, TO, SUBJECT
   - S/MIME signed attachment
```

Should I interpret the attachment as a nested / attached email as follows when decrypting?:

```
MimeMessage
   - FROM, TO, SUBJECT
   - MimeMessage attachment*
      - FROM, TO, SUBJECT
      - BODY
      - ATTACHMENTS
```

Or am I supposed to merge it with the root level items such that I end up with the following?:

```
MimeMessage
   - FROM, TO, SUBJECT
   - BODY*
   - ATTACHMENTS*
```

** decrypted*

Answer (score -1):

Your explanation of what you are seeing is very misleading as it implies that the decrypted content is itself an rfc822 MIME message structure.

The reality is that the decrypted S/MIME content *should* be a MIME entity, not a MIME message. Therefor, it will not have Subject, To, From, or Date headers.

In this case, yes, you would merge it with the container message if you want to get the original (pre-encrypted) MIME message structure.

Comment: I found that Thunderbird shows it as the main message merging it with the top level from, to and subject though. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Do what you want, but if you read the specs, that's 100% wrong.

Comment: Can you please link the spec.

Comment: Maybe you are mis-explaining something. Is the decrypted content itself a MimeMessage? Or does it just have Content-* headers? If it just has Content-* headers, then you are explaining it wrong and then yes, you need to merge.